# Sharepoint 2010 alternative to SetCtrlFromOpt

Tags: 2010, javascript

I have been tasked with debugging custom javascript which was originally written for 2007 by a 3rd party vendor.  The 2007 site has upgraded to 2010 and the javascript has stopped working.

The one bit which I can't seem to figure out fully is code which overwrites `SetCtrlFromOpt`.  In 2007, this function would get called whenever the value of a lookup field was select (those with more than 20 elements).

In 2010 this method is never called and does not seem to exist at all in the core Sharepoint js.  I was able to find `_SetCtrlFromOpt`, but this does not seem to get called either.

Does anyone know if there is some 2010 alternative to this function?  There must be something called when the element is selected from the dropdown, to copy from the `select` to the `input`, but I'm having a hard time finding this event as this `select` seems to be created dynamically when the arrow is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what javascript is called when item is selected (I'll try to make some investigations later). But may be this trick can help you: when lookup renders as input, this input has *optHid* attribute. The value of the attribute is an id of hidden input, that tracks currently selected lookup id. You can try to attach *onchange* event to this hidden input, so when *onchange* will be fire, it will be mean that lookup's selected value changed.

**edit**
Yes, setup onchange is a bad idea, it will never fire. But `_SetCtrlFromOpt` is exactly yours function. This method fires every time when item selected in lookup. In some mystic reasons I can't debug it using IE developers tools (it simply not hit the breakpoint), but I verify it using this javascript (place it on your list form):

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
      var oldset = _SetCtrlFromOpt;
      _SetCtrlFromOpt = function(ctrl, opt){
            alert("changed!");
            oldset(ctrl, opt);
       }
},"core.js");
```

`_SetCtrlFromOpt` declared in `core.js`, so we wait until it loaded and substitute with our function to check if it fires.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot.  Though I suspect that the event will likely not fire as the value is changed through javascript.  Unless Sharepoint explicitly fires it.

Comment: `_SetCtrlFromOpt` is your function, please refer to my update.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it again on Monday.  It didn't fire when I tried that but my guess is that something else was interfering.

Comment: Turns out the part I was missing was the `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded`.  In 2007 core.js is just included normally as a script.  Apparently in 2010 it is delayed, causing my script to be run first.  This did the trick.  Thank you.