# Dropdown lookup column in Sharepoint list form (newform.aspx)

Tags: 2010, list, jquery, dropdown

I have a dropdown lookup field in `newform.aspx` form. Unlike choice dropdown the lookup dropdown is `input` field and not `select`

So I raise an `onchange` event using jWuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input[title='Names']").change(function()...
```

Since sharepoint refers a lookup dropdown as a input field rather than select, if the index changes based on the values in the drop down box the change event does not fire.

But if I type in anything in the lookup dropdown box the event fires. What I'm looking for is to fire the event when the values from the dropdown are selected. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all some notes about this (weired?) sharepoint behavior (when html *select* renders as *input*). If you have a lookup field in your new\edit forms, this lookup may renders differently depending on browser and (wow!) items count in lookup list. When in lookup list items count less than 20, than all ok, in every browser lookup field renders as html *select*:[image]
On the image above it is an ie and *lookitup* refers to a list with 19 items. When we added one more item in lookup list situation is changed:[image]
and in ie only, all other browsers render *lookitup* as *select*. This is actually input with image, with number of event attached to provide suggest/filtering. This suggest/filtering feature works only in ie.
Ok, how to capture change event. @James Montagne recently [asked](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/sharepoint-2010-alternative-to-setctrlfromopt/27431#27431) this question. SharePoint 2010 has a js function called `_SetCtrlFromOpt`. This function fires on new\edit forms every time when value of "suggested" input is changed. You can catch it by substitute with custom function:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
      var oldset = _SetCtrlFromOpt;
      _SetCtrlFromOpt = function(ctrl, opt){
            alert("changed!");
            oldset(ctrl, opt);
       }
},"core.js");
```

You need to add this js code to your new\edit form. Here `ctrl` is a DOM input element, and `opt` is an element that represents suggestion dropdown. `opt.options[opt.selectedIndex].value` returns **lookup id** of a selected item in source lookup list, and `opt.options[opt.selectedIndex].text` returns lookup value.

**Note**: `_SetCtrlFromOpt` handles **all** lookup fields on the new\edit form, so if you have more than one lookup on your forms, and if you want perform some action only on the one of them, you need to filter all others events, that will be fired.

Comment: Thanks kai it works!!!...but the alert pops twice once when i open the drop down and i have to double click on the option to select(once)..and then when the selected option enters inside the dropdownfield(twice)...can we restrict it to jus pop up once..Thanks again!

Comment: Try to remove alert line, it seems that pop up with alert fire lose focus event, which fire `_SetCtrlFromOpt` again :). After removing alert all should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Dropdown lookupcoloumn in sharepoint forms may have some issue like this 
here is the way that I solved it:

```
var choices = $('[title="Title"]').attr("choices");     
var choiceArray = choices.split("|");
for(var i=0;i<choiceArray.length;i++){
if(choiceArray[i]==291){ // 291 is the LookupId of that LookupValue
console.log(choiceArray[i-1]); // The Lookupvalue that you required     
}
```

}