# Sharepoint 2007 lookup column

Tags: content-type, lookup-column, default-value

I have a site dropdown column using a list as the datasource (lookup). I was looking for a way to have the column be both required and have a default blank value. I read that is is not possible without code. My workaround was to add an item to the source list called "(select a value)". When I add this to the list, the lookup column on the form defaults to a blank value instead of (select a value). When I remove the item from the source list, the default value is always the first item in the list: "Alden". I don't get it. It exhibits the same behavior for any new values I add to the source list.

Even stranger, if I delete "Alden" from the list, it selects the second (existing) item: "Ann Arbor". If I add "Alden" back, it selects it as the default.

It seems items added after I set the list as a source for the site column don't come up as a default value.

Hope that makes sense...

Comment: I just though of something. Is it possible that some indexing has to run on the server first?

Comment: Hi Steve, instead of using the comment - you can update the update the question.

Answer (score 1):

When rendering a mandatory lookup column SharePoint will render it as a HTML `<select>` with only the valid entries and no blank entry. It'll mark the current `<option>` with the attribute `selected`. If the current (default) value isn't in the list then no entry will be marked as selected. The browser will show the `<select>` as a dropdown with the `<option>` marked selected as the current item, if no `<option>` is marked selected it'll use the first item as current.

Your options are:

- is either to make the lookup not mandatory of keep the "(select a value)" entry in the list. To prevent users from  posting without a value you'll then have to have an event receiver which will show a very user unfriendly error or do followup either manually or with a workflow.
- create a custom form

When you upgrade to 2010/2013 the first option and a validator will give a nice solution.

Comment: When I add the "(Select a facility)" as an entry in the source SP list the dropdown is attached to, the html of the dropdown shows as an <input> control but has events attached to it. when I delete the (Select a facility) item from the source SP list, the dropdown shows as a <select> control. This has me baffled...

Comment: This thread explains what is happening:

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28300/dropdown-lookupcoloumn-in-sharepoint-list-form-newform-aspx2010

If there are more than 20 items in a SP list, the dropdown bound to the list is rendered as an HTML input control; if not, then it is rendered as a select control. It had nothing to do with the value I was entering, it was because it was the 21st item in the list. 

Also, it appears a side affect of the dropdown rendering as a HTML input control is the default value for the dropdown is blank.