# Get value from drop down using jQuery (lookup column)

Tags: jquery, lookup-column, spservices, dropdown

I feel like this should be an easy one but am having trouble finding the answer here and via Google.  Using jQuery, how do I retrieve the *currently selected* value from a dropdown in an EditForm/NewForm.  The dropdown is a lookup column?

I've tried:

```
 $('#my_lookup_input_id').val()
```

Which returns a static value; if the drop down is changed, it won't alter the `val()` output.

I found [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28300/dropdown-lookupcoloumn-in-sharepoint-list-form-newform-aspx2010) but I am using SP2007. I need to be able to get the lookup ID/name pair from the dropdown in order to update another record from a different list using  SPServices and `GetListItems`.

Comment: You'd need an onchange or blur function if you need to check the value again.

Comment: Is it rendering as an input tag or a select tag?

Comment: Have you tried `$('#my_lookup_input_id :selected').val()` ?

Comment: @andrew.petersen15 - it is rendered as an `input` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after some more digging this morning and banging my head I found a solution using SPServices.  First, convert the field from a complex to a simple drop down:

```
$().SPServices.SPComplexToSimpleDropdown({  
    columnName: "myColumn"
});
```

Then, you can get the ID (and then the value) by using what SPServices has cleverly injected:

```
$('#SPComplexToSimpleDropdown_myColumn').val();
```

I'm still not sure of a way to do this without SPServices but I think it has to do with how SharePoint is doing funny business with the `input` field.

## PS: set the value

If you want to *set* the value of the dropdown you need to fire the `change()` event after setting it so the internal code gets tapped.

```
$('#SPComplexToSimpleDropdown_myColumn').val(15).change();
```

Comment: Glad you are sorted but there is definitely something odd going on because I have just tested a standard 2010 create and edit form with a lookup column and they are rendered as select tags.

Comment: @DavePaylor - I am using 2007, maybe that's the difference?  It generates a strange input field with lookups of more than 20 items that has a hidden input field that manages the value changes via javascript.  Or something.

Comment: i am having same problem, i am using SharePoint 2010. above script not working for me

Answer (score 3):

Use the F12 tools. Depending how many values are in your Lookup Field SharePoint will render it differently. I do believe the thershold is 20 items.

Under 20 the Lookup will render as a Select field. 
   ex $("select[title='"+ fieldTitle +"']").val();

Over 20
   ex $("input[title='"+ fieldTitle +"']").val();

if you want to get the ids of the input there is a attribute "optHid". Here is samples to get all values and ids.
    choices = $("input[title='" +fieldTitle +"']").attr("choices");
    hiddenInput = $("input[title='" +fieldTitle +"']").attr("optHid");

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#my_lookup_input_id option:selected").val()
```

This should get the selected value but as indicated by PirateEric you would need to call this again if the value changes.

Comment: So - that doesn't work for me.  If I do `$("#my_lookup_input_id").val()` I get the original value but if I do `$("#my_lookup_input_id option:selected").val()` I get *undefined*.  (same for just `:selected`).

Answer (score -1):

```
$("select[title='Lookup field Title'] :selected").text()
```